# Оптимизировать поиск текста в файле

Tags: java, io

У меня класс который ищет в файле нужный текст, и в случае успеха возвращает этот файл для дальнейшей работы с ним. Как можно оптимизировать скорость поиска?

```
public class ReadFile implements Read {
    private final StringBuilder sb;
    private final File file;

    public ReadFile(final File file) {
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public File read(final String target) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(this.file))
        ) {

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            if (new String(this.sb).contains(target)) {
                return this.file;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new File("-1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файл один и небольшой (меньше 1МБ), то оптимизировать скорость поиска особого смысла нет. Речь будет идти максимум о десятках миллисекунд. Можно лишь несколько укоротить код:

```
public class ReadFile implements Read
{
    private final File file;

    public ReadFile(final File file)
    {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public File read(final String target)
    {
        try
        {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
            String text = String.join("", lines);
            if (text.contains(target))
            {
                return file;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

Если же файлов много или есть один, но большой (например, 10МБ), то имеет смысл считывать файл не полностью, а ровно до того момента, как в уже считанной части будет найдена заданная строка:

```
@Override
public File read(final String target)
{
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int oldLength = sb.length();
            int fromIndex = (oldLength >= target.length()) ? oldLength - target.length() + 1 : 0;
            sb.append(line);
            if (sb.indexOf(target, fromIndex) >= 0)
            {
                return file;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Замеры скорости работы на файле в 10.2МБ.

1. Заданная строка в конце файла:

   ```
   1 вариант: 210мс
   2 вариант: 135мс
   ```
2. Заданная строка в начале файла:

   ```
   1 вариант: 205мс
   2 вариант:   2мс
   ```

---

Рассмотрение того, зачем сохранять `StringBuilder` в качестве поля (что, кстати, создаст проблемы при повторном вызове метода `read`), почему метод `read` называется именно так (учитывая что он занимается поиском строки в файле) и почему он возвращает `File` а не `boolean`, осталось "за кадром".

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. По поводу замечаний за кадров вы правы. Но только файл нужен для дальнейшей с ним работы.

Answer (score 1):

Если размер файла большой, то следует разбить его на "кадры" допустимого для вас размера. Кадры надо выровнять так, что бы они не разрывали слова по середине. Затем запускаете нужное количество потоков которые перебирают параллельно кадры (каждый поток - свой) выискивая в них нужную информацию.